Возможность создания категорий для пользователя
Я новичок в react, пишу некий туду лист но хочу добавить в него возможность создания категорий по кнопке, чтобы пользователь мог при нажатии на кнопку создать категорию и затем добавлять туда свои пункты, помогите пожалуйста

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Без вашего кода помочь ничем не сможем...

В чем сложность - объявить пернменную состояния и туда добавлять разделы по кнопке?
